# App engine RPC discovery doc

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, rpc, google-cloud-endpoints

I've been using app engine for Java with cloud endpoints to create a REST api and have suddenly run into this error:

`WARNING: No discovery doc for API hylytit version v1 in rpc format`

I'm trying to load the Javascript client library into a web page to do a `GET` call. In the web console, I see this:

`GET http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/hylytit/v1/rpc?fields=methods%2F*%2Fid&pp=0 [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 5ms]`

I'm unfamiliar with what RPC discovery docs are and can't find much online relating to App engine and RPC specifically. This is how I call the client library:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function start() {
    console.log("test.html onLoad function called.");
    var ROOT = "http://localhost:8888/_ah/api";
    gapi.client.load("hylytit", 'v1', function() {
        var req = gapi.client.hylytit.listUrl();
        req.execute(function(data) {
            //Do something with the data.
        });
    }, ROOT);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=start">
</script>
```

It seems that the App Engine plugin for Eclipse isn't generating the right RPC discovery docs. Any idea how to fix this?

**Edit**:
I have updated to the latest version of the Google Eclipse Plugin and the App Engine SDK as @Jenny suggested. I have also checked that all the cloud endpoint methods return valid types as @Ashish suggested, but continue to get the same error when I run it as a local server.

Interestingly, I have no issues when I deploy to app engine, only locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Willma, did you update your App Engine Eclipse Plugin or SDK recently?  If you did, try also update the Google Plugin for Eclipse.  Those plugins need to be in-sync for Google Cloud Endpoint Client library generation to work properly on Eclipse.  Once you update both plugins, the client library generation should work. Deploy the application to App Engine again, then you should be able to verify again based on the URL you showed above.

Comment: I suspected that this was the problem, as I got this error:

`There is a new version of the SDK available.
-----------
Latest SDK:
Release: 1.8.3
Timestamp: Fri Jul 19 13:04:55 EDT 2013
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Your SDK:
Release: 1.8.1
Timestamp: Fri Jun 07 10:37:10 EDT 2013
API versions: [1.0]

-----------
Please visit https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads for the latest SDK.`

But when I go into updates, it says that I already have 1.8.3 installed.

Comment: Fixed the above, but still getting the same error. Only happens when I deploy locally though.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have valid return types.
I was facing the same issue after using an invalid return type (boolean) for an ApiMethod. Note that GPE docs say, "In the Endpoint methods, the return value type cannot be simple type such as String or int. The return value needs to be a POJO, an array or a Collection."

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities

Comment: Thanks, I made sure the return types were valid. I actually had two `GET` methods with the same input variables, and thought that that was the issue, but the error persists. I've updated the question.